# kubernetes installation on AWS error (RouteAlreadyExists)

Tags: kubernetes

I started a Kubernetes cluster on AWS using:

```
wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

I then shutdown the cluster.  I then tried restarting it and get the following error:

```
A client error (RouteAlreadyExists) occurred when 
calling the CreateRoute operation: The route identified 
by 10.246.0.0/24 already exists.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the VPC was not correctly deleted.  After deleting manually, the installation proceeded as normal.

Comment: This may be a bug if kube-down.sh is supposed to take care of it.  I had the same issue trying to kube-up another cluster.